# How to cast an UIView in UIImageView / UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview, uiimageview

I have a scrollView who contain `UIWebViews` & `UIImageViews`.
I need to update this views, but I can't access to their properties.

```
for (UIView *subview in _scrollView.subviews) {
      if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
          subview.image = myimage;
      }
      if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]){
          [subview loadData:mydata MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
      }
}
```

My iterator is a UIView, so I can't access to .image UIImageView properties...

Thanks

Comment: Just create an `IBOutlet` and you can access your imageViews easy from there

Comment: UIWebViews and UIImageViews are created programmatically. I want to access to the UIImageViews & UIWebViews properties from an UIView. Look code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a cast expression:

```
((UIImageView*)subview).image = myimage;
```

*(or:)*

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)subview;
imageView.image = myimage;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIView *subview in _scrollView.subviews) {
      if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
          UIImageView *img = (UIImageView*)subView;
          img.image = myimage;
      }
      if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]){
          UIWebView *webView = (UUIWebView*)subView;
          [webView loadData:mydata MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id subview in _scrollView.subviews) {
  if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
      subview.image = myimage;
  }
  if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]){
      [subview loadData:mydata MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8"      baseURL:nil];
  }
}
```